# Contest platform protection from bad codes

Tags: python, c++, node.js, security

i have an npm "compile-run" library.

with child_process via node.js it will run the program code (c++,c,node.js,java,pytho )

my problem is that some of the commands out there are dangerous to me .
for example if python runs this code:

```
import os 
os.system("shutdown /s /t 1")
print(sum(map(int,input().split())))
```

I have a VDS server, so I can’t protect the site just for similar requests.
There is only one way for me `Gpedit.msc` but it is too much and I do not know exactly its performance classification.

how can i protect. there are so many cases here. file protection code protection.

**Does anyone know if codeforces.com, acmp.ru, leetcode.com have them on how to do this.**

*Help me thank you.*

but I could not limit it.

```
const {VM} = require('vm2');
const {c, cpp, node, python, java} = require('compile-run');

const vm = new VM({
    timeout: 1000,
    allowAsync: true,
    require: {
        external:true
    },
    sandbox: {
        require,
  console , 
    }
});
 
vmCode = `
const {c, cpp, node, python, java} = require('compile-run');
python.runSource(
`import os
os.system("shutdown /s /t 1")
print(1)\`, 
{ stdin: '', timeout: 3000, compileTimeout:3000  }   ,async(err, data) => {
      console.log(data)
});
`

try{
    vm.run(vmCode)
}catch(e){
    console.log("Err: ",e)
}
```

Comment: I am afraid this question is much too broad for SO. Also it is not about programming, but about system setup and therefore probably off-topic here. I don't know how exactly coding platforms are protected agains malicious code, but most likely they use some kind of virtualization, like a lightweight virtual machine for each session.

Comment: Yes, a very difficult question - should some things be chewed?

Comment: @JakobStark .. i added something new

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion to use Docker to avoid such issues:

- User's code may delete files but this affects only virtual environment and you can easily restart container from scratch (removing all dangerous changes).
- Docker allows to specify limits with flags like `docker run --cpus 1 --memory 10M`

You need to bind source directory, input and output files as [mount points](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) (together or individually) `-v /path/to/host/dir:/container/dir`.

Additionally, you may specify [no network connections](https://docs.docker.com/network/none/) using `--network none`.